# Unexpected behaviour assigning object to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

A very strange issue in my ExpressJS app.

My code:

```
console.log(req.user); // { user_id: '12345', name: 'Mr Example' }
var set = {};
set = req.user;
set['test'] = "testing";

console.log(req.user); // { user_id: '12345', name: 'Mr Example', test: 'testing' }
console.log(set); // { user_id: '12345', name: 'Mr Example', test: 'testing' }
```

Why does `console.log(req.user)` output the `test` property and value too? It seems to be copying whatever I do with the `set` variable. Why is this?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I didn't know about JS behaviour with pass by value and pass by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally normal... if you `set = <obj>` it only adds reference to that object, not creating new one.

Just change:

```
set = req.user;
```

to:

```
set = Object.create(req.user);
```

Please note that it won't rewrite old values, you have to do it yourself...

```
for (var k in req.user) { set[k] = req.user[k]; }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79vd3L7b/)

Or shorter version:

```
var set = Object.assign({}, req.user);
```

This one will copy all values.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79vd3L7b/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
set = req.user;
```

makes `set` refer to the same object that `req.user` refers to (throwing away the reference it used to have to the object created in the previous line). From that point forward, they're both just ways to get at the same object in memory. So naturally, any change you make to that object by accessing it through one variable is also visible through the other, as they're both just referring to a single object.

Remember that the value in a variable or property that refers to an object isn't the actual object, it's a value called an *object reference* that tells the JavaScript engine where the object is elsewhere in memory. The same object can have lots of different variables and properties referring to it.

Let's throw some ASCII-art (well, Unicode-art) at it:

After the `var set = {}` line, you have this in memory (leaving out some details):

```
         +−−−−−−−−−−+     
req−−−−−>| (object) |     
         +−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         | user     |−−−−>|      (object)      |
         +−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                          | user_id: "12345"   |
         +−−−−−−−−−−+     | name: "Mr Example" |
set−−−−−>| (object) |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         +−−−−−−−−−−+
```

But then you do `set = req.user`, and so you have this:

```
         +−−−−−−−−−−+     
req−−−−−>| (object) |     
         +−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         | user     |−−+−>|      (object)      |
         +−−−−−−−−−−+  |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                       |  | user_id: "12345"   |
set−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | name: "Mr Example" |
                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...and the object that `set` used to refer to doesn't have anything referring to it anymore, so it can be garbage-collected.

So of course, `set['test'] = "testing"` does this:

```
         +−−−−−−−−−−+     
req−−−−−>| (object) |     
         +−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         | user     |−−+−>|      (object)      |
         +−−−−−−−−−−+  |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                       |  | user_id: "12345"   |
set−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | name: "Mr Example" |
                          | test: "Testing"    |
                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Answer (score 0):

Because objects in javascript are **assigned by reference**.

This means that when you write

```
set = req.user;
```

You are saying "I want the `set` variable and the `req.user` variable to **reference** exactly the same object."

So if both `set` and `req.user` are pointing to the very same object, changing the value on one will change the value on the other.

When you `console.log` both `req.user` and `set` you are logging exactly the same object twice.

Answer (score -1):

**set** is a key word in javascript which it create new reference to existing object.. if you want to copy variable use some other variable reference instead of set.

```
console.log(req.user); 
var userData = {};
userData = req.user;
userData['test'] = "testing";

console.log(req.user); 
console.log(userData);
```